# Probability of choosing at least one vowel

Tags: probability

Three letters are chosen at random from word DRAWING.  What is the probability of choosing at least one vowel?

Comment: What's the probability of drawing no vowels?

Comment: Can you select the same letter more than once?

Answer (score 1):

I will calculate the probability of choosing no vowels. First you have a $\frac 57$ chance of not getting a vowel. Then you have a probability of $\frac 46$ (because 1 consonant was removed )and finally $\frac 35$

The probability of getting no vowel is the product of these 3, because the 3 events must happen. The probability of getting at least 1 vowel, is $1-\text{(probability of getting none)}$. Then:

$$P=1- (\frac 57 \frac 46 \frac 35) = \frac 57$$